# How to aggregate with "project.priority" in MongoDB query

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Here is a very simplified example of my data:

```
[
  { _id: 1,
    title: 'other item',
    category: 'show'
  },
  { _id: 2,
    title: 'THE ITEM THAT MUST BE RETURNED FIRST',
    category: 'show'
  },
  { _id: 3,
    title: 'other item 2',
    category: 'show'
  },
  { _id: 4,
    title: 'item not matching query',
    category: 'hide'
  }
]
```

I am trying to prioritize Id with the specific number at the top with sorting, had tried the same by in MongoDB:

```
itemsCollection.aggregate([
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 1,
    "category": 1,
    "title": 1,
    "priority": {
      "$eq": [
        "$_id",
        2
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  "$sort": {
    "priority": -1
  }
}
])
```

How can I try the same in C# using aggregate:

```cs
var aggregation = await collection.Aggregate()
        .Match(filterDefinition)
        .Facet(countFacet, dataFacet)
        .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `projection` and `sort`. Sometimes, it is hard to write in C# syntax, but you can work with `BsonDocument` which allows using MongoDB query syntax.

```cs
ProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument> projection = new BsonDocument
{
    { "category", 1 },
    { "title", 1 },
    { "priority",
        new BsonDocument(
            "$eq", new BsonArray
            {
                "$_id",
                2
            }
        )
    }
};
SortDefinition<BsonDocument> sort = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Descending("priority");

var result = await collection.Aggregate()
    .Match(filterDefinition)
    .Project(projection)
    .Sort(sort)
    .ToListAsync();
```

---

If you are returning a List of concrete type such as `List<Item>`,

```cs
public class Item
{
    [BsonId]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("priority")]
    public bool Priority { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var collection = _db.GetCollection<Item>("item");

ProjectionDefinition<Item> projection = new BsonDocument
{
    { "category", 1 },
    { "title", 1 },
    { "priority",
        new BsonDocument(
            "$eq", new BsonArray
            {
                "$_id",
                2
            }
        )
    }
};
SortDefinition<Item> sort = Builders<Item>.Sort.Descending("priority");

var result = await collection.Aggregate()
    .Match(filterDefinition)
    .Project<Item>(projection)
    .Sort(sort)
    .ToListAsync();
```

> Output

[image]

Comment: Parameters
group Type: MongoDB.Driver.ProjectionDefinition<TResult, TNewResult>
what should be the second parameter for ProjectDefinition?

Comment: Hi, are you using concrete class such as `Item`?